# Arithmetic operation order issue with a range

Tags: string, rust, range

I'm trying to learn Rust using the Rust book and the Exercism.io website.
I have an issue with [this specific exercise](https://exercism.io/tracks/rust/exercises/series/solutions/b969296d2ea146ce98a9fa27b599c269). The code is as follows:

```
pub fn series(_digits: &str, _len: usize) -> Vec<String> {
    (0.._digits.len() + 1 - _len)
        .map(|i| _digits[i..i + _len].to_string())
        .collect()
}
```

For example, `series("12345", 3)`should return a `Vec` containing `["123", "234", "345"]`.

Instead of `(0.._digits.len() + 1 - _len)`, I experimented using `(0.._digits.len() - _len + 1)` instead, but in this case, the unit test "test_too_long" fails:

```
#[test]
#[ignore]
fn test_too_long() {
    let expected: Vec<String> = vec![];
    assert_eq!(series("92017", 6), expected);
}
```

I'm surprised because it looks like it's the same to me. Why did it fail?

Comment: Check the error message. It says more than just test failed.

Comment: You were right, I didn't check and it helped me understand the issue. It's "attempt to subtract with overflow" x)

Comment: Do **not** prepend your variable names with an underscore (`_`). This is an indication that the variable is *unused*, which is not true for either of yours.

Comment: As a side note, your code would become a lot easier if you use `&[u8]` instead of the string types. Your `series` function would simply become `digits.windows(len).collect()`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in debug mode, arithmetic operations that would overflow instead panic, and panicking causes tests to fail.

With the rearranged version ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ede51787e162280f218ea84889e26e8)), in `series("12345", 6)`, `digits.len() - len + 1` becomes `5usize - 6usize + 1usize`. The program doesn't even get to the `+ 1`, because just `5usize - 6usize` panics. (`usize` can't represent negative numbers, so subtracting `6` from `5` causes overflow.)

The error message contains a strong hint at the nature of the failure:

```
---- test_too_long stdout ----
thread 'test_too_long' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', src/lib.rs:2:9
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

`digits.len() + 1 - len` works, however, because `6` is *exactly* one more than the length of the string, and so `5 + 1 - 6` can evaluate to zero without overflow. But if you change `test_too_long` to call `series("12345", 7)` instead, both versions panic. This seems like an oversight on the part of whoever wrote the test suite, especially considering that the instructions don't specify the expected behavior:

> And if you ask for a 6-digit series from a 5-digit string, you deserve whatever you get.

For what it's worth, here's one way to make `series` return an empty vector for any `len` greater than the length of the input: `(digits.len() + 1).saturating_sub(len)` is like `digits.len() + 1 - len`, but if the result of the subtraction would be less than `0`, it just returns `0`.